# Why is m2e not finding some of my snapshot dependencies from nexus?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus, m2e

In eclipse when I build I get the following warnings:

```
2/18/14, 4:30:35 PM MST: [INFO] Using org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.WarLifecycleMapping lifecycle mapping for MavenProject: com.foo:bar:14.4.19-SNAPSHOT @ C:\dev\code\apps\iv\pom.xml.
2/18/14, 4:30:35 PM MST: [WARN] The POM for com.foo.libraries:s2j:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
2/18/14, 4:30:35 PM MST: [WARN] The POM for com.foo.libraries:caching:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
2/18/14, 4:30:35 PM MST: [WARN] The POM for com.foo.libraries:email:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
...
```

And so on. The build does not complete and I am unable to get anything more in my target directory than the m2e-wtp/web-resources folder.

When I build from the command line, there are no issues, these artifacts are found just fine. They certainly are in my local repository, why does this happen?

**Some further details from experiments:**

Deleting my local repository and rebuilding in eclipse downloaded some of the artifacts, but resulted in more artifacts to not be found (originally I had 5 missing artifacts, now I have  7). Those that were not found were not downloaded from Nexus.

After having deleted the repository in the experiment above, I then built from the command line and those artifacts that had been listed as missing were downloaded and the build was successful. However, going back to eclipse results in the same errors (despite now having them in my local repository).

Inside eclipse when I "Run As" > "Maven Install" The missing artifacts are downloaded and are found. If I do an eclipse "Build Project" after this I still get the same issue.

Other projects within eclipse are experiencing the same issues on the same artifacts.

Comment: Are you using the same Maven settings in Eclipse as those used by the default maven install?  You can configure Eclipse to use an external Maven installation (Preferences -> Maven -> Installations). Also check the User settings file (Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings) and see if it is pointing to an appropriate file.

Comment: I am using an external maven installation, and my settings.xml file is pointing to the correct nexus server. The problem happened from some meta data getting mixed up after I closed these projects in my workspace (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me once. I've checkout com.foo:bar as well as com.foo.libraries:s2j, but I haven't configure the library as maven project in eclipse. So the maven install worked just fine (only the pom file was used), but the eclipse build failed.

So check that all the projects are configured as maven ones and try Maven > Update project and check Force update of snapshots and Clean projects.

Comment: This is certainly a maven project in eclipse (even has the little "m" on the top left corner of the project icon). Force updating and cleaning (either from the command line or from eclipse) does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Apparently when I did a mass close of workspace resolved projects some of them were left in a bad state. It looks like eclipse was trying to find the jar as a workspace resolved project, but the projects were closed and caused the result that they didn't exists (instead of looking at my local repository).

Once I opened (and then closed) the respective project for each of the missing dependencies they were then found in my local repository.